# Powershell nested for loop to restart services

Tags: powershell, command-line, invoke-command

My goal is to loop through all devices , stop a specific service for all of those devices ( in this case, IntenAudioService), then go kill speciifc tasks realted to that service ( let's just say task IntelX and task IntelY, if they exist)

Then just loop through again and re-start those services. can this be done all in 1 for loop? Is the syntax correct?

```
    $devices= <<user can populate devices in this object. DeviceName or deviceID??>>
    
    >Foreach ($device in $devices){
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device {
        net-stop IntelAudioService

         taskkill /IM IntelX.exe /F
         net start IntelAudioService
    }
}
```

What if I wanted to also set a service for each device? Something like this?

```
   foreach ($device in $devices){
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $device {
        Set-Service -Name BITS -StartupType Automatic
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, note that you can `Invoke-Command` to multiple hostnames at the same time. You can also create a `New-PSession` with multiple computers at the same time.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$devices = 'Hostname1','Hostname2'

$serviceName = 'IntelAudioService' # This can be an array
$processName = 'IntelX' # This can be an array

# Note: Looping through the devices an attempting to establish a
# PSSession like below is good if you're not sure if the remote host
# is up or if the device name is the right one, etc. Using a Try {} Catch {}
# statement in this case will let you know if you couldn't connect with a
# specific remote host and which one.

# You can also simply do: $session = New-PSSession $devices without
# any loop which will be a lot faster of course, however, 
# if you fail to connect to one of the remote hosts
# you will get an error and the the PSSession cmdlet will stop.

$session = foreach($device in $devices)
{
    try
    {
        New-PSSession $device
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service $using:serviceName | Stop-Service -Force -Verbose
    Get-Process $using:processName | Stop-Process -Force -Verbose
    Start-Service $using:serviceName -Verbose
    # Set-Service -Name $using:serviceName -StartupType Automatic
}

Remove-PSSession $session
```

Comment: What is PSSession needed for? Also, can you assist with the set-service part as well? Some services you can set as disable, automatic, etc... which is different than start service.

Comment: @encrypt I added a note to my code, check it out. I'm not sure what exactly do you want to know about `Set-Service`, from reading your code you're using it fine.